Preventing resulting shapefile being added to ArcGIS Pro map by ArcPy
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0 and I'm running an arcpy script. My script runs on the current map as I have a call referencing it. It gets a list of the layers currently in the map and runs select by location on each of them. Afterwards, it runs copy features to grab a copy of all the selected boundaries.
I intend to run this script multiple times. My issue is that at the end of the script, my results from the copy features process gets added back to the map. However, for future iterations of this script, I do no want to run the select by location for these added layers.
How do I make sure the results are NOT added back into the current map?
My current layers are (everything except for property boundary is point data):
Library, Property Boundary, Public Transit, Shelter, Hospital
import arcpy
#set project workspace
proj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
#find "Point to Property Map"
m = proj.listMaps("Point to Property")[0]
#features to pass through as inputs for select by location - everything except Property Boundary
#update path to change storage location
for item in m.listLayers():
    if item.name != "Property Boundary":
        selected = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByLocation('Property Boundary','Intersect',item)
        if "-" in item.name:
            item.name = item.name.replace("-","")
            name = str(item.name.replace(" ",""))+"_Property"
        else:
            name = str(item.name.replace(" ",""))+"_Property"
        path = "XXXXXX/"+str(name)
        arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(selected, path)

In my current result, it adds Library_Property, Hospital_Propertyetc. to the Point to Propertymap.

Set:
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False

Specifies whether the output datasets will be added to the application
display. This property is only applicable when used directly in the
Python window or from a notebook in ArcGIS Pro.

See: Environment settings
